# Feed Pull from Amazon s3 Bucket in a third party application

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I need your help or get some Idea in doing the Integration of s3 through a third party vendor application. I have some issues that I am not able to resolve, since I am not an expert with the Amazon s3 stuff.

So I have an application that is called Medallia and I am trying to perform a feed pull to export or download a file which is uploaded into the s3 bucket. I was able to figure out how to upload the file to the s3 bucket, but I am stuck on downloading the files or (feed pulling) the file to the app

I have added the information below for you to review!

Amazon s3 (Vendor Application Settings)

**pull method**: Amazon s3

**Feedpull**: feedpull.va.dev.us-west-1.medallia

**Amazon s3 access Key**: AKIA****(Confidential)

**End Point**: s3-website-us-gov-west-1.amazonaws.com

I have added the URL from where i took the end point from. I am not sure if i have to use *Web or Storage*. (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/govcloud-us/latest/UserGuide/using-govcloud-endpoints.html) Please inform!

**Why am I doing this?** 
- So that I can have the files that gets uploaded to Amazon s3 bucket be pulled on schedule every end of the week to update/maintain the third party application.

**Additional Info Needed (If Possible)**
I need to have the python installed and have a Command to COI and then drop files on to the s3 bucket. This will help me to test the s3 Bucket (on the web services) through Automatic feed pull.

ERRORS

- **Before no end-point**

Error while pulling feedpull. The configuration is using the wrong endpoint for the specified bucket for s3. exception: nonfatal error.

- **After end-point**

Error while pulling feedpull: s3 Pull (feedpull I)Unable to execute HTTP request. Connect timed out. One possible cause is a malformed endpoint. nonfatal error exception.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, your question is difficult to understand -- are you saying that you wish to download some files from S3 once per week? How do you determine which files you want? What does "feedpull" mean? Your question mentions Python, but you tagged it with PHP and Ruby -- which language are you using? Your 'feedpull' appears to be in us-west-1, but your S3 URL shows us-gov-west-1 -- which region are you using? Can you show us the code you have written so far?

Comment: Well sorry for making you confused on this topic. The coding is done in Python to have the file be uploaded to the amazon s3 bucket, but NOW I want to have that file be "Downloaded or uploaded" to the application (which uses Amazon server) to Feed pull which means Pull file through SFTP network on schedule - weekly from the s3 bucket. Automatic feed pull can be accomplished by having the s3 be set up on to the third party application.

Answer (score 0):

The web site hosting endpoints are for unsecured, publicly-accessible content, and don't support authentication... so that isn't likely what you are looking for.

Assuming you're working in US GovCloud, you want one of the REST endpoints:

```
s3-fips-us-gov-west-1.amazonaws.com
s3-us-gov-west-1.amazonaws.com
```

The first one is FIPS 140 Level 2 compliant, so I would suggest that this is the one you want, unless you have a reason not to.

Comment: Thank you so much! you have resolved this issue for me.